# Why prove theorems about conditional expectation separately?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am taking a graduate course in probability. We are proving many theorems for conditional expectation that hold for normal expectation. Why is it not possible to do in some simpler way? Is there some theorem that would allow transferring theorems from usual expectation to conditional expectation?

(This question is related but distinct to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3934300/why-have-separate-definitions-for-expectation-and-conditional-expectation) I had on why we have to have two definitions at all)

Comment: "Normal" expectations are simply conditional expectation w.r.t. the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, so in fact you don't have to prove everything twice. Whether it is "simpler" to define things like this I'm not sure.

Comment: Good point! However, I would expect that conditional expectation works the same as normal expectation (defined as integral w.r.t. $P$) so it should be possible to use the weaker (as you point out) statement about the normal expectation to conditional expectation. This would make proofs simpler (and the situation less confusing for students).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What are you suggesting exactly?

Comment: You suggested that theorems for conditional expectation hold for normal expectation. I am suggesting it should go the other way around.

Comment: I am not aware of any proof that does that.

Comment: Are you aware of something that holds for normal expectation but not for conditional?